# How to call the indexPath.row of a UITableViewCell with a UICollectionView embedded within

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

Currently, I have a UITableView with a UICollectionView embedded in it. I have 3 arrays of information and I want each array to correspond to a UICollectionView, and therefore a UITableViewCell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CookieCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuCollectionViewCell
        cell?.fullView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell?.labelView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell?.fullView.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        cell?.labelView.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        return cell!
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
```

Where each of the `return cell?` is, I want to do something like:

```
if indexPathOfTableView.row == 0 {
//designated parameters
}
else if indexPathOfTableView.row == 1 {
//designated parameters
}
else {
//designated parameters
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Is there any chance you could move to iOS13 and compositional layout with a single collection view? This kind of thing is so much easier now

Comment: If not, in the outer table view cellAt method, pass the index path to the cell that you return. 

That cell will have a collection view and its itemAt will have the inner indexpath and access to the outer one that was passed in

Comment: In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` pass the tableView indexPath to the collectionView.

Comment: @Rob could you give me an example of this? I am still new to Swift

Comment: How about you post the contents of your tableView cellForRowAt method, and the definition of your tableView cell? We'll go from there.

Comment: @Rob I added the empty method for cellForRowAt within the first segment of code, where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @helloworld12345

from your question I got the idea that you want to collectionview in tableviewcell

may be below code will help you.

first in you viewController or tableviewcontroller,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
  //send indexPath of this cell 
        let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCell

   //Pass your array which you want to show in collectionViewCell and then reload collection view

        cell.clnView.reloadData()

        return cell
}
```

In your tableViewCell swift file:

```
 class tableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout 
{

   @IBOutlet weak var clnView: UICollectionView!

   //after awakenib method write below code

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return 4 //pass your array count
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let flowayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let space: CGFloat = (flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
    let size:CGFloat = (self.clnView.frame.size.width - space) / 2.0 //By this you can show two cell in one screen
    return CGSize(width: size + 60, height: (size + 200))
}


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "clnViewCell", for: indexPath) as! clnViewCell


 // do your stuff with your 
    return cell
}

}
```